# How do you get your program to print out the number of values a user has entered?

Tags: java

For example, if a person entered the numbers 22,44,55,33,77,443. It would print out "6 numbers have been entered".

Comment: Entered how? As program arguments? Via a text field? Do you have some code so far?

Comment: With Object Oriented Programming? Vague question, vague response. Show some code

Comment: String s= "22,44,55,33,77,443";                                                                                        s.split(",").length

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for `String.split`, for example:

```
String input = "22,44,55,33,77,443";
System.out.printf("%d numbers have been entered\n", input.split(",").length);
```